# clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 Qt Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

Unable to build Qt examples . Getting error while building in windows

```
 E:\android-ndk-r20-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r20/toolchains/aarch64-linux- 
 android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux- 
 android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lc++
 clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
 invocation)
  make: *** [libanalogclock.so] Error 1
```

Qt SDK and NDK configuration

[image]

Qt version

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. I did alot of google research on this but i could not find a solution yet. Since it seems to be a new problem with "cannot find -lc++" (thats the message i see in QT Creator) i wonder if older QT Versions may work. I am using QT 5.12.3 and QT Creator 4.9.1, JAVA SE 8 and latest SDK and NDK versions. But older QT versions, so i have read, need NDK Version not higher than 10. (Which i tried as well with 5.12.3)

Answer (score 3):

The error: `cannot find -lc++` using ndk r20 can be solved like this:
https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/264903/9/mkspecs/android-clang/qmake.conf#34

For example to compile for android armv7 ndk r20, locate the file:
`C:\Qt\5.13.0\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang\qmake.conf`
and add the missing `-nostdlib++`
for android x86 (i use this for emulator), locate the file:
`C:\Qt\5.13.0\android_x86\mkspecs\android-clang\qmake.conf`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://forum.qt.io/topic/103713/error-cannot-find-lc-qt-5-12-android/5) installing [ndk version 19](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases) should fix it. Did it for me.