# Unable to build Android app on Windows using QtCreator

Tags: android, qt

After not being able to compile a Python app for Android using pyqtdeploy on my Linux machine I now have tried to build a sample app on Windows using QtCreator. I got the same error as on Linux: 
**cannot find -lc++**
Here is the command that produces the error.

```
C:\Users\Art\android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target i686-none-linux-android -mstackrealign -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\Art\android-ndk-r20/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot=C:\Users\Art\android-ndk-r20/platforms/android-16/arch-x86/ -Wl,-soname,libcalculator-qml.so -Wl,-rpath=C:/Qt/5.12.4/android_x86/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libcalculator-qml.so calculator-qml.obj Button_qml.obj calculator-qml_qml.obj qmlcache_loader.obj statemachine.obj   C:/Qt/5.12.4/android_x86/lib/libQt5Gui.so -Lc:\Utils\Android\android-ndk-r19c/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86 C:/Qt/5.12.4/android_x86/lib/libQt5Scxml.so C:/Qt/5.12.4/android_x86/lib/libQt5Qml.so C:/Qt/5.12.4/android_x86/lib/libQt5Network.so C:/Qt/5.12.4/android_x86/lib/libQt5Core.so -lGLESv2  -LC:\Users\Art\android-ndk-r20/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86
```

Has anbody got any idea?

Comment: Btw..I have the same error on Linux building this sample in QtCreator

Comment: seems to relate to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621970/clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-qt-android

Comment: Yes right...but this is also unresolved

Comment: I resolved the issue, see my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621970/clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-qt-android

Comment: Thanks. I did not tried your solution, but using ndk 19 helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case other people are running into a similar problem.
I could solve the problem switching back to **ndk-19**.
I will also try Albertino80's solution someday.